# How to correctly build EF5 Code-first model with two or more lists that relate to the same child table?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following models:

```
public class SomeForm
{
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public IList<FacilityContactInformation> OriginatingFacilities { get; set; }

     public IList<FacilityContactInformation> DestinationFacilities { get; set; }
}

public class FacilityContactInformation
{
    public FacilityContactInformation()
    {
        Id = -1;
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

I am using automatic migrations to gen and re-gen the database schema.

This generates the error "Foreign key 'FK_dbo.FacilityContactInformations_dbo.SomeForm_SomeForm_Id ' references invalid column 'SomeForm_Id' in referencing table 'FacilityContactInformations'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I suspect the root cause is that EF tries to generate a FK FK_dbo.FacilityContactInformations_dbo.SomeForm_SomeForm_Id for both lists

Is there any way to keep using automatic migrations, but get this to generate a FK that works?  It would seem like the FK should include the list name and generate two properties on FacilityContactInformations  OR should generate an intermediate table to join on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have 2 navigational properties that link to the same class, you should override OnModelCreating method of your dbcontext class. Then add this code into the OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeForm>
  .Hasmany<FacilityContactInformation>(x => x.OriginatingFacilities);

modelBuilder.Entity<SomeForm>
 .Hasmany<FacilityContactInformation>(x => x.DestinationFacilities);
```

This is because EF cannot determine the correct keys if the nav. prop. link to the same class.

Comment: I still don't totally 'get' why EF can't divine this from the model on it's own, but this worked as advertised.  Thanks!